# How to use <select> tag in php table?

Tags: php, html

I want to add this to my php table below. I want it formatted to work as php  field in my table. This exemple is a html code I want it to look like 
`echo "<td>" . "<select value=" ???????? " </td>";`
Please stop downoting me. I am not an English speaker. I am just doing my bets to make you guys understand what I want.

```
<select id="state1" name="name1">
    <option value="Resolved">Resolved</option>
    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
    <option value="Cased">Cased</option>
    <option value="Resolved" selected>Resolved</option> 
</select>
```

how to insert the above in this table?

```
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)) {

              echo "<form action=edit_c_log.php method=post id=modif>"; 
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['device_id'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";                  
              echo "<td>" . "<select name=status ?????????? " </td>";                                                   
              echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=status value=" . $row['status'] . " </td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=pending_reason value=" . $row['pending_reason'] . " </td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=case_number value=" . $row['case_number'] . " </td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=call_id id=edition value=" . $row['call_id'] . " </td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit id=insert10 name=update value=update>" . " </td>";
              echo "</tr>";
              echo "</form>";   
        }
```

**edit_c_log.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php               

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user2';
$dbpass = 'Pw32';
$dbname = 'db3';

$con=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

if(!isset($_SESSION['log_update'])){
$_SESSION['status'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['status']);
$_SESSION['pending_reason'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST  ['pending_reason']);
$_SESSION['case_number'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['case_number']);
$_SESSION['call_id'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['call_id']);

$status = $_SESSION['status'];
$pending_reason = $_SESSION['pending_reason'];
$case_number = $_SESSION['case_number'];
$call_id = $_SESSION['call_id'];

Mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE oz2ts_call_logs SET status='$status', pending_reason='$pending_reason', case_number='$case_number' WHERE call_id='$call_id'");

 }

?>
```

Comment: Please note that a form is not allowed to be a child element of a table, tbody or tr.

Comment: @fusion3k It is not an additional form it is just like another input field

Comment: *"I use the form to edit MySQL data. when I do it like that, any selected option doesn't is not get edited"* - Oh, so the plot thickens then! I had a feeling there was more to this, and `$row['status']` was the giveaway and `INSERT THE <SELECT> HERE`.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  haha, agreed, It was too easy of a question, especially with `****INSERT THE <SELECT> HERE **** ` to not have a dirty hidden secret.

Comment: @Jean I know it, but when you declare the form (in second piece of code), you declare it before a `<tr>` element, inside (i suppose) a `<table>`

Comment: @andre3wap Yeah, without seeing your comment here, I added that `INSERT THE <SELECT> HERE` being another *dead giveaway* ;-)

Comment: too many unknowns here. you seem to want to update an SQL table but not showing us that and whether it's relevant or not. I'll pass on this question. Good luck

Comment: @andre3wap  The only think I want is how to convert the Html <select> to fit it in my php table the same way I wrote the <input> field. Do not worry about the rest

Comment: @Jean - go look at my answer below. I revised it the way how you are asking it for. Let me know if we can be of any more assistance.

Comment: @andre3wap   Thank you so much that is what I wanted. I have a quick question. I have the same table in html but when I use edit_c_log.php I posted above, it will update only the last row of the table why is that?

Comment: @Jean - There are a lot of moving pieces here, but I suspect that you are having the issue because you do not post back the data with each form having their own array, and then looping through while updating..

Comment: @andre3wap  I will work on that thank you

Comment: @Jean - If my answer works for you, please accept it with the check mark so that others can benefit. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: `"(In PHP format)"`

```
    echo "<form action=edit_c_log.php method=post id=modif>"; 
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo '<select id="state1"  name="status">';
                echo '<option value="Resolved">Resolved</option>';
                echo '<option value="Pending">Pending</option>';
                echo '<option value="Cased">Cased</option>';
                echo '<option value="Resolved" selected>Resolved</option>';
            echo "</select>";
        echo "</td>";             
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=status value=" . $row['status'] . "> </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=pending_reason value=" . $row['pending_reason'] . "> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Thank you. I use the form to edit MySQL data. when I do it like that, any selected option doesn't is not get edited

Comment: Are you attempting to get the selected value from `$name1 = $_POST['name1'];` ?

Comment: no I just want to know how to format <select> in php table. In my example, it is written in html format

Comment: *..no I just want to know how to format <select> in php table. In my example, it is written in html format..* What can we predict now @Jean ?

Comment: @Jean - Whether the `elements` are enclosed with `echo '` / `format in php as you call it` etc, that does not matter. I am under the impression that your goal is to update the data within the DB once a user toggle the options in the select and submit the form, correct?

Comment: @andre3wap   Yes I want to update the DB if option is selected.

Comment: @Jean - ok good. 1. Use the code that I revised above. 2. edit your original question and post the portion of your `PHP` code that does the `update` to the DB.

Comment: @andre3wap I just edited my question with more data and the php  doing the edit of the db data

Comment: @andre3wap I do have the same form in html but the use the same edit_c_log.php will edit data only if it is the last row in the table. I think I need to edit edit_c_log.php to use a full html table

Answer (score 0):

I think, the better way use html code like html. Like this:

```
<form action="edit_c_log.php" method="post" id="modif">
<table>
   <tr>
       <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
       <td>
           <select id="state1"  name="name1">
               <option value="Resolved">Resolved</option>
               <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
               <option value="Cased">Cased</option>
               <option value="Resolved" selected>Resolved</option> 
           </select> 
       </td>
       <td>
          <input type="text" name="status" value="<?php echo $row['status'] ?>"
       </td>
       ....
</table>
</form>
```